# Inserting single curly braces to Tcl list elements

Tags: tcl

I have a report file having multiple lines in this form:

`str1 num1 num2 ... numN str2`

Given that (N) is not the same across lines. These numbers represent coordinates, so I need to enclose each point with curly braces to be:

`{num1 num2} {num3 num4}` and so on...

I have tried this piece of code:

```
set file_r [open file.rpt r]
set lines [split [read $file_r] "\n"]
close $file_r
foreach line $lines {
    set items [split $line]
    set str1 [lindex $items 0]
    set str2 [lindex $items [expr [llength $items] - 1]]
    set box  [lrange $items 1 [expr [llength $items] - 2]]
    foreach coord $box {
        set index [lsearch $box $coord]
        set index_rem [expr $index % 2]
        if {index_rem == 0} {
            set box [lreplace $box $index $index "{$coord"]
        } else {
            set box [lreplace $box $index $index "$coord}"]
        }
    }
    puts "box: $box"
}
```

This gives me a syntax error that a close-brace is missing. And if I try `"\{$coord"` the back-slash character gets typed in the `$box`.

Any ideas to overcome this?

Comment: Can you get an unpaired list of coordinate values? Pairing them up with `lmap {a b} $coords {list $a $b}` is easy.

Comment: How would I get it? I don't know the number of points as it varies from a line to line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could improve to have better and simpler Tcl style.

1. You usually don't need to use `split` to form a list from a line if the line is already space separated.   Space separated strings can almost always be used directly in list commands.
   The exceptions are when the string contains `{` or `"` characters.
2. `lindex` and `lrange` can take `end` and `end-N` arguments.

This plus Donal's comment to use `lmap` will result in this:

```
set file_r [open file.rpt r]
set lines [split [read $file_r] "\n"]
close $file_r
foreach line $lines {
    set str1     [lindex $line 0]
    set str2     [lindex $line end]
    set numbers  [lrange $line 1 end-1]
    set boxes [lmap {a b} $numbers {list $a $b}]
    foreach box $boxes {
        puts "box: {$box}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Attention, your first recommendation is only valid iff the OP has full control/ authority over the content of `file.rpt`. In Tcl, *not* all whitespace-separated strings are valid string reps of a Tcl list. So better pre-process the string in `$line` using a command that returns a valid list for sure. `subst` is one, `regexp -inline` is recommended in general: `set line [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]`.

Comment: Agreed.  Curlies and double quotes in the string will be a problem when treating it as a simple list.

Comment: So ... you might want to add to your answer?

Comment: I had originally said that strings with spaces can "almost always" be used like lists.   Sure, I'll update the answer.    I had just wanted to point out that splitting a string to make a list is not always required in Tcl, unlike in Python where strings can never be treated like lists.  In fact, extra whitespace, like in `[split "a       b"]` will return `a {} {} {} {} {} {} b`
`

Comment: exactly the latter is a case one might not expect, at all :) therefore, Tclers' Wiki recommends the `regexp` stanza.